# Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -f ./temp/*") Platform dependent

Tags: java, linux, windows

I need to clean a temp directory when the application closes.
On Linux and Mac the following command is working perfectly:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
  Debug.infomess("clean exit");
  try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -f ./temp/*");
  } catch (IOException e1) {
    Debug.errmess(e1,"Exit error");
  }
  System.exit(0);
}
```

What is the Windows equivalent of ' rm -f ' Linux command.

Comment: Use the built in libraries, such as `File` and/or `Path` to access files and directories. And don't use the `Runtime`

Comment: You can use `deleteOnExit();` method in `File` class. Files marked in such way will be deleted when JVM exits gracefully